# 2D arrays in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am using 2D arrays to create a weekly calendar that handles different appointments and converts appointment times to military times.

Below is my getAppointment method and for some reason I am getting errors with the first return statement. Its saying that 'hour' is the wrong type and that i am supposed to have an int but i declared in the header that day and hour are ints. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
/**
 * Retrieve an existing appointment (if any) by day and hour.
 * 
 * @param day  The day to check (0-6).
 * @param hour The hour to check (0-23), in military time.
 * @return The appointment at the specified day and time,
 * if there is one, or null if no appointment is found, if
 * the day specified is invalid, or if the hour specified is
 * outside the range 8-17.
 */
public void getAppointment(int day, int hour)
{
    if ((day >= 1 && day <= 7) && (hour >= 0 && hour <= 23))
    {
        return app[day - 1][hour - 8];
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    } 
}
```

Comment: your method is declared to not return any value. A return statement with an expression is illegal in such  a method.

Comment: Just a quick recommendation: using an IDE (e.g. Eclipse which is free btw), can help avoid such mistakes and save a lot of time and effort in the process.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that in your `if` statement hour could be e.g., 0. In that case you are trying to return `app[day - 1][-8]`. This results in an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Also your method is not supposed to return anything (void).

```
public Appointment getAppointment(int day, int hour)  // added return type (see below)
{
    if ((day >= 1 && day <= 7) && (hour >= 8 && hour <= 23))  // changed this to >=8
    {
        return app[day - 1][hour - 8];
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    } 
}
```

(I assumed you made an Appointment object that is stored in your app array and that this is going to be the return type)